# how do i change the image for each row in this list view

Tags: java, android, image, listview

im new to android and java and i created a my own adapter and list view from a tutorial I was following online. I want to know how do i the image for each individual row because my adapter (from the tutorial) only has 1 image for all the rows. here is the code for my own adapter.

```
class HangarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public HangarAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.hangar_layout, values);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.hangar_layout, parent, false);

    String ship = getItem(position);

    TextView theTextView = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    theTextView.setText(ship);

    ImageView theImageView = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    theImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);

    return theView;


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
theImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
```

This line above is what you have to change in order to use a different images;

```
you could potentially do something like this;
if (position == 0){
   theImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
} else if (position == 1){
   theImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
}
```

It also depends on the backing data.